# How to get data with removed duplicates?

Tags: oracle

The code below is to get distinct data in terms of column name e1 and mdl, but does not show any reslut.
I have put "AND ROWNUM IN (SELECT MAX(ROWNUM) FROM T1.." to remove dulicated row.

If I remove "AND ROWNUM IN (SELECT MAX(ROWNUM) FROM T1..", then of course all the data in Table T1 selected.

```
    <Table and data>

    CREATE TABLE T1  (  
      dte VARCHAR2(15),
      gu1 VARCHAR2(15),
      gu2 VARCHAR2(15),
      eq VARCHAR2(15),
      mdl VARCHAR2(15),
      val VARCHAR2(15)  
      );

    INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('20190801','30','30','E1','M1','1.5');  
    INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('20190801','30','30','E1','M1',NULL);  
    INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('20190801','30','30','E1','M1','0');  
    INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('20190802','30','30','E1','M1','1.5');  
    INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('20190803','30','30','E3','M1','3.0'); 



    <Code>

    SELECT gu1,gu2,eq,mdl
    FROM T1
    WHERE val <> '0' AND val IS NOT NULL
    AND dte >= '20190801' AND dte <= '20190803'
    AND gu1 = '30'
    AND ROWNUM IN (SELECT MAX(ROWNUM) FROM T1   --to get only one among dulplicated rows in terms of column e1, mdl,
        WHERE val <> '0' AND val IS NOT NULL
        AND dte >= '20190801' AND dte <= '20190803'
        AND gu1 = '30' 
        GROUP BY eq,mdl)
    ;


   <Expexted result is>
    GU1  GU2  EQ    MDL
    ---- ---- ---- ---- 
    30   30   E1    M1
    30   30   E3    M1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rownum is generated after the row is output. what you can do instead is to use 
row_number analytical function as follows

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT gu1,gu2,eq,mdl,row_number() over(partition by eq,mdl order by dte desc) as rnk
    FROM T1
    WHERE val <> '0' AND val IS NOT NULL
    AND dte >= '20190801' AND dte <= '20190803'
    AND gu1 = '30'
   )x
WHERE x.rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SELECT DISTINCT` Statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
gu1,gu2,eq,mdl
FROM T1
WHERE val <> '0' AND val IS NOT NULL
AND dte >= '20190801' AND dte <= '20190803'
AND gu1 = '30'    
;
```

More info on `DISTINCT` use [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from sample data and expected output, You can use one of the following method:

1. `Distinct` - as decribed in VSMent answer
2. Using `rownum` - as described in George Joseph answer
3. Using `EXISTS` as described following

-- in following example, you can also use `WITH AS` to remove excess duplicate coding

```
SELECT T1.gu1,T1.gu2,T1.eq,T1.mdl
FROM T1
WHERE T1 val <> '0' 
AND T1.val IS NOT NULL
AND T1.dte >= '20190801' 
AND T1.dte <= '20190803'
AND T1.gu1 = '30'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM T2   
        WHERE T2.val <> '0' 
        AND T2.val IS NOT NULL
        AND T2.dte >= '20190801' 
        AND T2.dte <= '20190803'
        AND T2.GU1 = 30
        -- FOLLOWING 3 CONDITION WILL RESTRICT DUPLICATE ROWS
        AND T1.EQ = T2.EQ
        AND T1.MDL = T2.MDL
        T1.ROWID > T2.ROWID
        );
```

Cheers!!